# Is designing a website like designing a API

Tags: python, django

So

I am a student and haven't being doing this for too long.

I've started to use Python/Django and noticed that when you are going to a new page you link the url in `urls.py` to your view for that url.

If you're also posting data to say a url then in the `views.py` file for that function you'll decorate it with `@require_POST` or `loginrequired` etc...

So when creating APIs can you just do the same thing, the only difference seems to be that in this case the requests are ocming from within the django app (local) and with an api requests are external.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: **no**.

- designing an API needs to focus on usability and reuse.
- designing a website is more about capturing traffic, and have people stay longer (e.g. ad revenue); it seems to be more about presentation and delivery.
- designing a django application involves choosing what your URLs look like (e.g. use slugs in addition of primary keys) which is only one aspect.

An API endpoint is usually very much different than what people most commonly refer to as a "website".